# Find and Replace HTML tag using SED in Shell

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, sed

What I want to achieve is, replace a html tag with modified tag in file using Shell script. When I googled for find and replace using Shell, I came to know about SED. I tried for my purpose, but it throws the error. My code is,

```
pattern='<html style=background-color:#ffffff;>'
replacement='<html style=background-color:#ffffff; manifest="app.appcache">'

cat "index.html"  | sed "/s/$pattern/$replacement/" > "index2.html"
```

I'm getting the below error,

```
sed: 1: "/s/<html style=backgrou ...": invalid command code <
```

From few other stackoverflow questions, I tried without using

```
pattern='<html style=background-color:#ffffff;>'
replacement='<html style=background-color:#ffffff; manifest="app.appcache">'

sed "/s/$pattern/$replacement/" <"index.html" >"index2.html"
```

I'm getting the same error.

Please help me how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
#    v-- no leading slash
sed "s/$pattern/$replacement/" index.html > index2.html
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be done like this:

```
pattern="<html style=background-color:#ffffff;>"
replacement="<html style=background-color:#ffffff; manifest=\"app.appcache\">"

sed "s/$pattern/$replacement/g" index.html > index2.html
```

Comment: If you replace the `'`s around the patterns with `"`s, the `"`s inside the patterns will be discarded by the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers,
It's working with '@' which I got from a blog

```
sed -e 's@<html style=background-color:#ffffff;>@<html style=background-color:#ffffff; manifest="app.appcache">@g' <"index.html" >"index2.html"
```

Comment: The error wasn't the `@`. Look at Wintermute's answer. The only problem was the leading slash.